# Can I write a single-tab web application using IE8?

Tags: internet-explorer, web-applications, session

My collegues facing one problem with IE8. they have one page for Product selection. now if user opens the page and selected one product as well as its some properties.. then he/she opes a new tab with same page... and selects a new product then the session used for page is shared by both the tab pages... 
so, can anybody provide solution to store data which can not be shared by 2 tabs in IE8

Comment: I'm not sure that's possible. It sounds like you're asking for a way to store session data that's not saved in a session, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: What do you store in the session? and what is shared?

Comment: Yes, this is why navigational information goes in the URL and not in the session.

Answer (score 2):

If web programming is done properly, it works exactly as you described.

This is known as a [REST](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) model.  The identical web pages in your two tabs are a result of two GET operations to the same URL.  When you submit one of the tabs, you do a POST.  If you change the information in the second tab and submit it, another POST occurs, updating the database with the information from the second tab.

It's by design.

[How I explained REST to my wife](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284)

Comment: The article "REST to my wife" unfortunately looks to have been taken down

Comment: @andrewb: Due to rampant political correctness.  A mirror can be found here: http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284.  Note that no wives were harmed in the making of the original article.